# Python (requests) - incorrect encoding when fetching headers

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using requests library (python 3.9) to get filename from URL.<sup>[1]</sup> For some reason a file name is incorrectly encoded.
I should get "Ogłoszenie_0320.pdf" instead of "OgÅ\x82oszenie_0320.pdf".

My code looks something like this:

```
import requests
import re

def getFilenameFromRequest(url : str, headers):
    # Parses from header information
    contentDisposition = headers.get('content-disposition')
    if contentDisposition:
        filename = re.findall('filename=(.+)', contentDisposition)
        print("oooooooooo: " + contentDisposition + " : " + str(filename))
        if len(filename) != 0:
            return filename[0]

    # Parses from url
    parsedUrl = urlparse(url)
    return os.path.basename(parsedUrl.path)

def getFilenameFromUrl(url : str):
    request = requests.head(url)
    headers = request.headers
    return getFilenameFromRequest(url, headers)

getFilenameFromUrl('https://przedszkolekw.bip.gov.pl'+
    '/fobjects/download/880287/ogloszenie-uzp-nr-613234-pdf.html')
```

Any idea how to fix it?
I know for standard request I can set encoding directly:

```
request.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

But what am I supposed to do with this case?

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
https://przedszkolekw.bip.gov.pl/fobjects/download/880287/ogloszenie-uzp-nr-613234-pdf.html

Comment: There's a library "fix that for you" https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ that might help you if you can't solve this the proper way. It automatically fixes problems like this so you don't have to.

Comment: OS: Windows 10, language: polish

Comment: I applied the changes needed to make it reproducible. It's still not a [*minimal*-reproducible-example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimal-reproducible-example) - this is a one-time service. Please keep in mind that you should care about the work needed by others. Thanks!

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow") is of course easier to read than the collection linked in above comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only characters from the ascii based [latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) should be used as header values [[rfc]](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5987).  Here the file name has been escaped.

```py
>>> s = "Ogłoszenie_0320.pdf"
>>> s.encode("utf8").decode("unicode-escape")
'OgÅ\x82oszenie_0320.pdf'
```

To reverse the process you can do

```py
>>> sx = 'OgÅ\x82oszenie_0320.pdf'
>>> sx.encode("latin-1").decode("utf8")
'Ogłoszenie_0320.pdf'
```

(updated after conversation in comments)

Comment: @Lucas Also works with `filename.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`. Btw, wrt _"only ascii characters should be used as header values"_ - that's _correct_ but there's clearly an `Å` in the header. I suspect it's because the server is incorrectly decoding the filename for the string version - and browsers know to handle this situation. +1

Comment: @Wolf Yeah, I noticed that happening too. So instead, I went the long way round - with the filename copied to clipboard, did `pd.read_clipboard().columns.values.tolist()[0].replace('"', '')`

Comment: If [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a 7-bit encoding, there *must be something wrong* with the header.

Comment: @Wolf I can see it in the browser and in SublimeText but not in the terminal. And for me, a different translation occurs when I paste `Ogłoszenie_0320.pdf` into the terminal: `Ogoszenie_0320.pdf`.

Comment: @wolf I just tried this is a python shell in iTerm2.  I have my shell encoding set to en_US.UTF8

Comment: @aneroid thanks for the suggestion for clearing up the language.  The Å is valid extended ascii https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/capital-letter-a-ring-uppercase-ascii-code-143.html